# The form cannot be displayed in the browser because the use of session cookies

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer

I have googled the problem, but couldn't find a solution for it. They are talking about underscore in the URL but in my case there is NO underscore(_) just an Hypen (-)....

**Problem description**

When I click on a list item to do display/edit then I get the error message below. I've set the in Internet Options, Privacy --- Accept All cookies(means met the slider to bottom), but the problem still appears, I can't see detail item or edit item, what could be the problem?

**I'm using**

- Windows 8 to access from home our companies SharePoint 2010 site using Internet Explorer 11. I've installed on my local pc MS office 2010(word, excel, InfoPath....) and SharePoint Designer are installed.

**My company site looks like:**

https://mysite-collaboration.prod.domain.com/Name/RECORD
it has a hypen (-) not underscore(_).

**At work (internally):**

I don't have problem at work. I'm using IE10.

**From home:**

I've that problem when I access SharePoint from Home. So can't do Display/Edit on items from home.

Error message:

> The form cannot be displayed in the browser because the use of session cookies has been disabled in the current browser settings. In order to load the form, session cookies must be allowed.

Comment: Same issue see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d36d7808-cfcb-4ca4-bb99-0c2a22d08ea9/session-cookies-must-be-allowed?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy[link]

Comment: Another one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f88cc9fe-2c8d-4258-a494-f5a804bde6c7/the-form-cannot-be-displayed-in-the-browser-because-the-use-of-session-cookies-has-been-disabled-in?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  your sharepoint site to "Trusted sites" security zone.
And In IE 11 try to add your sharepoint site to compatibility view settings list(Under the "Tools" menu).

Comment: Today I checked at home in the evening and it's already there in the trusted site.

Comment: Then you can install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on client machine and watch what is realy going on qith cookies.

Comment: I see, can do that in the evening when I'm back at home pc home. :( at home it's not working. so I will start Fiddler and then go to the page and look on the things coming, do I need to check upfront things in Fiddler?

Comment: I have tried several options, but none of them worked. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should check the following

- Change IE setting to “always allow session cookies”. from Tools >
  Internet Options > Privacy Tab > Advanced.

  Add Site URL to Compatibility View List. from Tools > Compatibility
  View Settings.

  Add Site URL to Local Intranet Sites.from Tools > Security > Local
  Intranet.

  Clear cache and cookies. from Tools > Internet Options > General >
  Browsing History > Delete.

  Turn off Pop-up Blockers. from Tools > Pop-up Blockers > Turn off.

  try to access the form on different machines and browsers.

if this not solve the problem you should follow this [link](https://mohamedelkassas.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/the-form-cannot-be-displayed-in-the-browser-because-the-use-of-session-cookies-has-been-disabled-in-the-current-browser-settings-in-order-to-load-the-form-session-cookies-must-be-allowed/) that discuss the same issue

Hope this info is help you